# CGAffineTransformation set the anchor?

Tags: iphone, cgaffinetransform

I'm curious about something.  In my app I'm running an animation where a view is resized a little bit.  I'm creating the transform like this:

```
CGAffineTransform resize = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
```

However, when I apply this transformation to my view and watch it run, it resizes from the top and shrinks towards the bottom.  What I'm wanting is where it resizes evenly on all sides and shrinks towards the center, as if an "anchor" point is in the center.  You know what I'm saying?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply a `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` to move the origin to the center -- composite them into a single transform with `CGAffineTransformConcat`

Answer (score 4):

First add the Quartz framework to your project and import the Quartz header

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then you can set the anchor point of your view like this

```
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

AnchorPoint points are values between 0 and 1. 0,0 is the top left corner on the iPhone.

Comment: What would be the center, then, if it's between 0-1?

Comment: Well, the problem is I didn't mean the center of the window, I mean I wanted to window to resize toward the center of itself.  It's actually offset from the center quite a bit.  Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: That's what this should be doing. Setting the anchorPoint to 0.5, 0.5 means the center of the layer, which should be as big as your view if you didn't resize it. But I'm glad you found your solution :)