# Rotation around different anchorPoint and position makes image jump to new position first

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

I'm doing a rotation animation on a view and want it to rotate around the view's center X and bottom Y. I change the anchorPoint and position of the layer and run the animation. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _imageView = [UIImageView newAutoLayoutView];
  _imageView.image = [PCImage imageNamed:@"Umbrella"];
  [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
  [_imageView autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis:ALAxisVertical];
  [_imageView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(_imageView.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(_imageView.frame));
  NSLog(@"frame %@, new position %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_imageView.frame), NSStringFromCGPoint(newPosition));

  _imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, 1.0);
  _imageView.layer.position = newPosition;


  [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:.1 animations:^{
      _imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 64);
    }];
  } completion:nil];
}
```

**edit**

The rotation is working, but the view 'jumps' upward to a new position first, where the view's bottom is now where the view's center Y was when first laid out. I thought changing the anchorPoint and updating the position would prevent the jumping. The view is pinned to the superview's bottom edge, and center X to the superview's center X in autolayout, if that might matter. Any ideas?

**edit2**

I've read other good posts on this like the following but I must be missing something..

[Scale UIView with the top center as the anchor point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007983/scale-uiview-with-the-top-center-as-the-anchor-point)

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: hi @robmayoff, i read some of your posts regarding the jumps - thanks for those - but still unable to get this working. the view is autolayout, not sure if that's part of the problem. the frames are being animated after layout occurs in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the view to not use autolayout after reading this post:

[Adjust anchor point of CALayer when autolayout is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used)

Looks like transforms and autolayout aren't designed to work well together.

```
_imageView = [UIImageView new];
_imageView.image = [PCImage imageNamed:@"Umbrella"];
_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, kScreenHeight - _imageView.image.size.height, _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:_imageView];
```

At some point hoping to experiment with other ideas in that post.